# Not getting it right with AFNetworking & create/update with ObjectivRecord (Core Data)

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, afnetworking, exc-bad-access

I am using AFNetworking to fetch JSON objects from the server. I then use ObjectiveRecord to create data object (Core Data). Sometimes I search and update objects. This works well in the simulator on, as well on my iPhone 5. However when using an iPhone 5S it does not work. I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when doing an `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` (in ObjectiveRecord code).

Reading a lot of articles about Core Data and threading, this has led me to believe that I should use private context, using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

I use the suggested way to set this in ObjectiveRecord, that is:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]   initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
newContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[CoreDataManager instance] persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

I then use `createInContext:` to create my objects in the completion block of AFNetworking.

I have found a similar question on SO, but it does not use ObjectiveRecord: [Get a number of resources asynchronously and "asynchronously" save them to a database. Which good pattern to use? (AFNetworking, Core Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790923/get-a-number-of-resources-asynchronously-and-asynchronously-save-them-to-a-dat)

However I do not get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Can you try enable `NSZombie` that might catch the crash cause, of course its not related to `AFNetworking` something to do with CoreData implementation. Does the same code work fine in other devices?

Comment: To enable `NSZombie`, go to `MenuBar` -> `Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme`, and then click on the `Diagnostics` tab. Enable the check box for `Enable Zombie Objects`. You will see something like `-[UITableView release]: message sent to deallocated instance` in your log instead of throwing an exception. It should help you figure out which object has been deallocated.

Comment: This problem only occurs on iPhone 5S. See question ;-)

I will try to use NSZombie to see if I could get some more hints.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this to work. Probably because my skills in Core Data was not enough. Therefore I switched to [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) instead. It was easier to understand how to use it in a multithreaded environment than [ObjectiveRecord](https://github.com/supermarin/ObjectiveRecord). It´s a shame that there is no good article on how to use [ObjectiveRecord](https://github.com/supermarin/ObjectiveRecord) in a multithreaded environment.